# About aps_developer_identity.cer related

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I downloaded my push notification certificate "aps_developer_identity.cer" from apple developer portal, and installed it. This certificate shows up only in the "certificates" filter and not in "My Certificates" filter in my keychain. Where am I going wrong? I need to export the ".p12" of "aps_developer_identity.cer" and upload it to UrbanAirship for testing purpose. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have the private key signing the certificate in your Keychain. If that's not the case, revoke the old certificate and generate a new one with one of your private keys.